# Intersecting polygons in Oracle

Tags: intersection, oracle-spatial

Have a polygon in table 2 with its id, no and geometry. In table 1 I have polygons with the same fields. The polygon in table in intersects with a few polygons from table 1.What I am trying to do is clip of the polygons which overlap polygon from table 2 and insert the same fields and geometry in table 3

```
insert into table 3  
select a.store_id,b.store_id,a.store_number,a.client_id,sdo_geom.sdo_intersection(b.geometry,a.geo metry,0.005)  
from table_1 a, table_2 b  
where b.store_id=34746  
and sdo_anyinteract(b.geometry,a.geometry)='True';
```

When I do run this I dont get any output. Where would I be going wrong

Comment: please see
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78008/how-to-check-for-overlapping-polygons-in-oracle

Answer (score 1):

This query will fail with ann error like this:

```
ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine
ORA-13207: incorrect use of the [SDO_ANYINTERACT] operator
```

You need to write "= 'TRUE' " instead of " = 'True' " (notice the capitals).

Apart from that, the query is also incorrectly written: since you lookup table A using a window from table B, then you need to specify the columns in that order in the spatial predicate, so write
   sdo_anyinteract(a.geometry,b.geometry)
instead of
   sdo_anyinteract(b.geometry,a.geometry)

So the proper way to write your query is this:

```
insert into table 3  
select a.store_id, b.store_id, a.store_number, a.client_id, 
  sdo_geom.sdo_intersection(b.geometry,a.geometry,0.005)  
from table_1 a, table_2 b  
where b.store_id=34746  
and sdo_anyinteract(a.geometry,b.geometry)='TRUE';
```

That may still return no rows. It all depends on the actual data you are using.

Comment: Also make sure that you have a spatial index on `table_2.geometry` column.  Without it, the operator `sdo_anyinteract` may fail.

Comment: Not true: table_2 does **not** need a spatial index for the spatial operators to work. An index **is** required only on the table/column that is the **first** argument to the operator (i.e table_1 in this example). You only need a spatial index on table_2 if that is also used for spatial searches = it is used as the first argument in a spatial operator - that includes the SDO_FILTER used for *viewing* the data. So, it is a good idea to have a spatial index on all spatial columns (even though table_2 does not require one for the above query).

Comment: In rare cases I have seen the oracle optimizer drive the join in the revers order.  As in, the A position is driving, not the B. In this particular case it is unlikely, but I think it could happen if you had far fewer rows in table_1 than table_2 (after the predicate is applied).  Either way, in specific cases Oracle will drive the query from the reverse order.  On older versions (9i I think) this fails without the index.  Newer versions this succeeds, but takes longer because there isn't an index to use.